# How to find boundary voxels (pixels) using a binary mask, to get only the segment surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

His is my first question here, so please direct me if anything. I briefly describe the situation: there is a voxel set of sizes 512x512xN (N is the number of tomography slices) (new BitArray (512x512xN)). As a result of one of the segmentation algorithms, the indices of the filled voxels in this set are obtained; the BitArray array is used to indicate the required voxels, where indices with the value true are the segment and false is the background. So I would like to know how to find boundary voxels (pixels) using a binary mask, which stores their coordinates (x, y, z) and background information or not (true - false)), to get only the segment envelope. Here is the code for defining the bounding indices, but it is not correct:

```
private static async Task<BitArray> EdgeArray(Vector3Int size, BitArray data)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var edges = new BitArray(data.Length);
            var mask3d = new Dictionary<Vector3Int,bool>();

            Parallel.For(0, data.Count, i =>
            {
                lock (mask3d)
                {
                    mask3d.Add(size.GetIndex3D(i),data[i]);
                }
            });

            var voxels = mask3d.Keys.ToList();

            Parallel.For(0, voxels.Count, i =>
            {
                if (voxels[i].x == 0 || voxels[i].x == size.x - 1 || voxels[i].y == 0 ||
                    voxels[i].y == size.y - 1 || voxels[i].z == 0 || voxels[i].z == size.z - 1)
                {
                    if (mask3d[voxels[i]])
                    {
                        var index = voxels[i].ToIndex3D(size.x, size.y, size.z);
                        edges[index] = true;
                        Debug.Log(index);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mask3d[voxels[i]] && (!mask3d[voxels[i-1]] || !mask3d[voxels[i+1]]))
                    {
                        var index = voxels[i].ToIndex3D(size.x, size.y, size.z);
                        edges[index] = true;
                        Debug.Log(index);
                    }
                }
            });
            return edges;
        });
    }
```

Secondary functions:

```
/// <summary>
    /// returns the index in the 3d representation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector3Int"> array size in 3d representation </param>
    /// <param name="index"> 1d index </param>
    /// <returns>index in the 3d representation</returns>
    public static Vector3Int GetIndex3D(this Vector3Int vector3Int, int index)
    {
        return new Vector3Int
        {
            z = index / (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y),
            y = index % (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y) / vector3Int.x,
            x = index % (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y) % vector3Int.x
        };
    }
    
public static int ToIndex3D(this Vector3Int vector3Int, int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        return vector3Int.z * width * height + vector3Int.y * width + vector3Int.x*depth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you GetIndex3D() and ToIndex3D() functions might be wrong.
ToIndex3D() should be:

```
return vector3Int.z * width * height + vector3Int.y * width + vector3Int.x;
```

and GetIndex3D() should be:

```
z = index / (vector3Int.x * vector3Int.y),
y = (index / vector3Int.x) % vector3Int.y
x = index % vector3Int.x
```

(this is an untested guess from memory, but I think it's an OK way to convert a 3D array to a 1D array and vice versa)